# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error on XMLHttpRequest

Tags: api

beginner here so please be gentle. For some time I've been trying to get a json file from the Walmart API using a XMLHttpRequest and always get that error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey={apikey}&upc=035000521019.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm using an Apache server in which I have inserted the following code into the httpd.conf file , specifically to get rid of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. Still nothing.

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Accept cross-domain requests
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Please note that I will not give my API key here for obvious reasons, but while coding I inserted in the url the API key that Wal Mart gave me. The problem is not on the Wal Mart side because when I type the url in Chrome it get the text content of the JSON file. So... Here's my code, please help, I'm f#cking clueless.

```js
function ajaxGet(url,callback){
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url);
    req.addEventListener("load", function (){
        if (req.status>=200 && req.status<400){
            callback(req.responseText);
        } else {
            console.error("Erreur no." + req.status );
        }
    });
    req.send(null);
}

function setHtml(texte){
    var ouin = JSON.parse(texte);
    var product = slashString(ouin.items[0].categoryPath);
    var brand = ouin.items[0].brandName;
    var price = ouin.items[0].salePrice;
    document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = brand;
    document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = product;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;

}

function slashString(texte){
    var n = texte.lastIndexOf("/");
    var texte = texte.slice(n+1, texte.length);
    return texte.toLowerCase();
}

ajaxGet("http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey={apikey}&upc=035000521019",setHtml);
```